Must a continuous injection of a closed disc to itself that is identity on boundary be a homeomorphism?
Apologize if this is a dumb and/or well-known question.
Let $n\geq 1$ be a positive integer, $f: \mathbf{D}^n\rightarrow\mathbf{D}^n$  be a continuous injection that is identity on the boundary $\mathbf{S}^{n-1}=\partial \mathbf{D}^n$.
Must $f$ be a homeomorphism?
I am aware of this question, from which it follows that $f$ is surjective, hence bijective since $f$ is assumed to be injective. But I do not see a way of showing that $f^{-1}$ is continuous.

Isn't an embedding by definition a homeomorphism from $D^n$ to $f(D^n)$? In that case you would need to show $D^n\subset f(D^n)$. Maybe via contradiction? (Suppose not, ...)

Ah that’s right (embedding = homeomorphism onto image with induced topology)! Let me change embedding to continuous injection. Thank you @user408858.

This boils down to (a special case of) the following basic result:
Proposition Let $f : X \to Y$ be a continuous bijection where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Then $f$ is a homeomorphism.
Proof. Let $C \subseteq X$ be closed. Since $X$ is compact, $C$ is compact, and so $f(C)$ is compact. Since $Y$ is Hausdorff, $f(C)$ is closed. This shows that $f$ is a closed map, and since $f$ is a bijection, we conclude that $f$ is an open map. Now $f$ is a continuous open bijection, a.k.a. a homeomorphism. $\square$

Thank you @diracdeltafunk!

You're welcome :)

But one still needs to show that $f(D^n) = D^n$.

See this (mentioned in the main text of the question). @Ulli

@aaa acb: yes, I'm aware of it. However, the same proof for higher dimensions still works, but involves even more algebraic topology. Compared to this, the above answer is the easy part!

You just need to know that $H_n(S^n)$ is nontrivial, which is also pretty elementary imo

FWIW I’ve written my (hopefully bug free) proof for surjectivity in arbitrary dimension as an answer to the linked question, following @diracdeltafunk’s hint.
